# Windows 10 IoT Core (15063) administrator password error on setting up a new device

Tags: passwords, windows-10-iot-core, change-password

When setting up a new device using IoT Dashboard, the password entered for Administrator is not properly saved on the image. This is happening when using % sign in the password string.

Answer (score 0):

The process of image creation does not encrypt (or at least hash) the password onto the card. It just copy a bunch of files and on top of them, in EFIESP folder, is placing a batch script **PreProvisionDevice.cmd** created from user input. The script is processed at first boot and contains the following instructions:

```
REM SQM-machine-id
reg add HKLM\Software\Microsoft\SQMClient /v MachineId /t REG_SZ /d 4d8b6b44-180f-450a-abce-de862265091a /f
REM Change the adiministrator password
net user Administrator "myPassWith%percent"
REM Remove the password change prompt from DevicePortal
reg add HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\IoT\WebManagement\LoggedInUsers /v Administrator /t REG_DWORD /d 0x1
REM Change the computername
set computername minwinpc3
REM Reboot the device for changes to take effect
shutdown /r /t 5
REM delete the provisioning file and the wifiprofile
del %systemdrive%\EFIESP\WiFiProfile.xml
del %0
```

On the 4th line, you may see the 90's, funny, old school, **net user** command. And the unescaped percent. The correct version shall be "myPassWith%%percent". The lesson already learned, we conclude:

- avoid an initial password with percent
- if you already made it, at the login use the password ignoring the percent
- a Pandora's box is hidden there. What if using %0 variable or && concatenation in the password string? And the list may continue...